# Какой UI Spy позволяет увидеть идентификаторы элементов меню и подменю?

Tags: windows

Мне нужно сравнить, как устроены меню и подменю в `calc.exe` и в том приложения, которым я пользуюсь. Оно написано на *C++* с применением *WTL*.

Испробовал:

- RanorexSpy.exe
- MS Spy++ идущий вместе Visual Studio

Ни одно из этих  решений не подошло: не позволило увидеть идентификаторы элементов управления.

Как только перехожу к подменю и делаю <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, чтобы прицепиться *Spy-ем* к процессу исследуемого приложения, то меню сразу же после нажатия на <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> перестает быть активным.

Прошу помочь с Выбором *UI Spy*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Удовлетворился применением:

- c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x64\inspect.exe